# how to format an integer output in JavaScript to add , with every 3 numbers

Tags: javascript

Example = 123456789 = 123,456,789

is there any function that does the above or should I create one ?

Thank you

Comment: @HaoWu thousand separator would give this `1,234..` but he wants this `123,345,..`

Answer (score 1):

Intl.NumberFormat has a *localized* number formatting.

That means if your browser is set to English you will get your expected format, but if the browser is set to German it will return the German format.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

```
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"
```